# Approach To Building Expression Tress with Dynamic Objects

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression-trees

I'm looking for help on how to approach an interesting issue.

We have code that will build expression trees (LINQ) to search/sort/paginate a collection of strongly typed objects. The Expression Tree code uses reflection to build up the expression trees and will work an any collection (as long as it's strongly typed).

```
IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(Request request, IQueryable<T> queryableData) where T: class
// Request Contains the searching/sorting/pagination criteria eg: FuzzySearch: "FindAnyObjectWithThis"
```

We recently had the request to be able to customize the fields that where being searched/sorted on. Basically the user could select columns dynamically to include/exclude. To accomplish this, we started by using dynamic objects (ExpandoObject) but this broke the parsing functionality for there was no underlying type for reflection to use.

1. We could change the Parse to use DynamicLinq to parse the collections but that would require us to change the Parse function.
2. We could attempt to dynamically build a type and instantiate the type when retrieving the original data but this could prove to be slow.
3. An approach we haven't thought of.

Has anyone else done anything similar to this? How did you approach it?

Comment: When you're doing everything dynamically it's a very strong sign that you shouldn't be using LINQ at all.  It's *specifically* designed for data schemas that are known at compile time.  You're almost certainly better off just using more traditional forms of querying that are inherently designed to be dynamic to begin with.

Comment: I should mention that the Parse function isn't strictly limited to this feature, it is used elsewhere. What other traditional forms are you referring to?

Comment: Building a SQL string.

Comment: You're also assuming that the underlying data is all SQL. The data comes from several different sources (Web Services, SQL, etc..)

Comment: Which is why I said you should use a more traditional non-LINQ method, to cover all of those cases.  I doubt whatever it is you're using can *only* be accomplished using LINQ.  Use whatever mechanisms you had before LINQ was an option.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that clear cut for this situation. Data may be coming from different sources and combined and cached. I think trying to adopt what you're suggesting would require a lot more rework than any of the above options.

Comment: The point is that if this is the type of operation you need to perform that query probably shouldn't have been written using LINQ in the first place.  You shouldn't be exposing a method such as this because this isn't an operation that is designed to done using LINQ (which is why you're going to have a very hard time trying to use LINQ to do this).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62270/discussion-between-chad-kapatch-and-servy).

Comment: Why should what the user sees affect this method in any way? If the user shouldn't be able to sort based on some property, that doesn't mean `T` can't have that property.